# Visual Studio 2022 Missing Many View | Other Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. It is missing many items and is not really usable.

For example, under View | Other Windows, there are just three items:

- Stack Trace Explorer
- Package Manager Console
- IntelliSense

1. There should be many more. In particular I installed the Python Development workload, and I later installed the VS History 2022 extension. (Both show in the installer.) The Python Environments window and the Visual Studio File Histories window should be there, but they aren't. Alt-I should bring up the Python Environments. It just dings.

I have checked the installer. Python development is checked. Python is, in fact, installed.  It is at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python
```

2. There is no Git on the toolbar.
3. Under Tools | Options there is nothing for Git, Python, or VS History Files as there is for Visual Studio 2019.
4. In addition there is no External Tools option under the Tools menu as there is for Visual Studio 2019.
5. In the lower right where it should show the Commit button (for a solution which has a Git repository) there is "Add to Source Control" (which does nothing).

I have Googled and found no one else with these problems. There are plenty of articles, such as how to use the Python Interactive window and Tools | External Tools explicitly mentioning Visual Studio 2022. So it must something I have not done, but I cannot find it nor determined how to fix it.

I have restarted the computer several times. It has not fixed it.

I have been using Visual Studio since at least Visual Studio 2008 and am an experienced user. I have never had these kinds of problems installing the next version. I am able to work on a Windows Forms project, at least to build and run it (but not to commit the changes). I do not seem to be able to do anything else.

Any help would be appreciated.